# Converting RGB to ARGB

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I'm trying to emulate the Color.ToArgb() Net function in VB6.

For my attempts I have chosen the color Red.

In .NET I'm getting the result

```
Color.Red.ToArgb() = -65536
```

However, I'm not able to reproduce this in VB6.

My function RGBToARGB(vbRed, 255) returns -16776961

```
Public Function RGBToARGB(ByVal uColor As Long, ByVal uAlpha As Integer) As Long

    Dim newColor As Long

    ' To add an Alpha channel to the RGB, simply
    If uAlpha > 127 Then
       newColor = uColor Or ((uAlpha - 128) * &H1000000 Or &H80000000)
    Else
       newColor = uColor Or (uAlpha * &H1000000)
    End If

    RGBToARGB = newColor

End Function
```

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong / different than the .NET version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more optimal way to do this but this should work:

```
Function RGB24ToARGB(ByVal RGB24 As Long, ByVal Alpha As Byte) As Long
    RGB24ToARGB = CLng(Alpha And Not &H80) * &H1000000
    If Alpha And &H80 Then RGB24ToARGB = RGB24ToARGB Or &H80000000
    RGB24ToARGB = RGB24ToARGB _
               Or (RGB24 And &HFF&) * &H10000 _
               Or (RGB24 And &HFF00&) _
               Or (RGB24 And &HFF0000) \ &H10000
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is correct.

The reason why the results are different is because byte order in color values is different in VB6 and VB.NET. `vbRed` in VB6 is a constant that is equal `255` (`&H0000FF`), and the .NET's Red color is `&HFF0000`.

If you call your function as `RGBToARGB(&HFF0000, 255)` it will give the result you expect.

This is the reason there is [`ColorTranslator.FromOle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromole(v=vs.110).aspx). `ColorTranslator.FromOle(vbRed)` would give you `Color.Red`.

Comment: Thank you. I need to stay conform with the .NET version. Do you know how I can change my function in such a way that will work with whatever color as long as I feed it in VB6? Thank you.

Comment: Your function already does what the .NET version does. It's just that you pass different data to it. `vbRed` is not equal to `Color.Red`.

Comment: Thank you, I'd appreciate it if you would say more about it.

Comment: @tmighty: Which part do you need help with? This answer is as clear as it gets. Your code is correct. Your input is wrong. If you need to convert between VB6 representation and VB.NET representation, this answer points you to a pre-built solution.